# Can we boosting or stacking with different input variables for each model in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, neural-networks, bagging, stacking

I have a question about Boosting and stacking in machine learning. Suppose that I will train neural network, SVM and logistic regression using optimization algorithm to optimize best inputs in first phase. So now I have 3 trained models with different combination of inputs.
Can I use these trained models (based on different input's variables of each created model) for boosting or stacking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you are familiar with this topic. If not, read [Ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) on Wikipedia.

Now, to your question. First *boosting*. Here, you use a meta-algorithm to improve an (one) algorithm. It usually does a good job, but sometimes it over-fits, meaning that It appears to be better, but it actually isn't. For your problem - yes, you can use boosting on each of the used algorithms.

As for *stacking* - here, you run all of the algorithms at once, and then make a decision which of them you will use for the final decision (somewhat similar to voting). You usually make this decision with logistic regression (in your case, you will have two different instances of logistic regression as you already use one for solving your problem).

If you want to use both *boosting* and *stacking*, you first have to boost each and every one of your algorithms, and then use another algorithm (e.g. logistic regression) to stack them into an ensemble.

Comment: Thank you for your answer alesc. I don't want use both boosting and stacking together. My general question : Can we combine models (For example using boosting or stacking or...-Ensemble learning) that have different input variables? or it is forbidden based on theory of ensemble learning? I think based on your answer, the answer is yes. we can use. Is this true?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to comment on that part. You usually use the same input for all of the algorithms in an ensemble, but I don't see a reason why It wouldn't work. But I can't say anything regarding if it would be better or not. Do you have a good reason not to use the same input? Did you perhaps perform a Feature selection and come with different attributes for different algorithms?

Comment: That's true. I used a feature selection in first phase because there isn't any good theory for selecting inputs in my problem. So I have different inputs in every created model. For example I have separate trained models NN,SVM & LR with differed selected inputs. I want know how can I use ensemble learning in this situation to combine all models.

Comment: In that case, it should work fine. Because removing some attributes was a kind of mini-boosting for each of your algorithm. Are there major differences between the algorithms or do they perform similar? If one is significantly better than the others, then maybe you don't even need to make an ensemble.

Comment: The accuracies are almost the same. For instance 87% for NN,82% for SVM and 80% for LR but type-1 error is so impotent for me. I'm coding a GUI and I want use ensemble learning as a feature in this software + I used 10-fold cross validation for creating every model and an optimization algorithm to optimize and select input variables (feature selection).

Comment: 10-fold CV is not a good method for optimizing your models as you do not have an external and fixed test set. The 10-fold CV uses the same instances to train and validate and is therefore biased. You need to do the following: Separate the dataset into two groups (train and test) with a ratio of let's say 80:20. Then, you use 10-fold CV only on the train set to optimize the model and afterwards you test it on the test set. And then repeat until you are satisfied. Also, when separating into train/test, stratify your data beforehand (if you are dealing with a classification problem).

Comment: I'm repeating this cross validation in a loop for 8 times so We have random test indices and test accuracies so in every iteration of optimization algorithm I have 10*8=80 test accuracies. I will average between them to calculate every iteration accuracy. As you said this is true that I don't have same test indices for all checks but in my method the confidence is higher than using only one bunch of test indices for all tests. What do you think?

Comment: You need an external and unbiased test set that you can test your optimized model on. This is the only thing that works. I have done many research on this topic and I can only say that 10-fold CV sometimes over-fits the data and gives _false hope_. Repeat your procedure on only 80% of the data, and after you optimize your model, test it on the remaining 20%. If the accuracy is the same, then good for you. If not, your optimized model is not OK because it is over-fitted.